# Graphical Btrfs tool

Tags: debian, partition, gui, btrfs

Is there a graphical tool for creating Btrfs sub-partitions and in particular, subpartitions like "GParted" or "system-config-lvm"? I'm running Debian squeeze.

In response to the first comment, Btrfs can do thinks like RAID and sub-partitions, much like LVM. I've read that Btrfs can be seen as a replacement for LVM. LVM has a graphical tool to manage these aspects, does Btrfs have the same?

Comment: `gparted` is a tool for  creating/resizing partitions, LWM is a system to manage logical volumes ("Partitions" that can grow and shrink, and even span physical disks), BTRFS is a filesystem type. Please sort out what you want. I'd think the graphical installer for Debian is close to what you are asking?

Comment: See edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`btrfs-gui`](http://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-gui) might be what you're looking for. It doesn't do much yet, last time I tried it. You are much better off with `btrfs-progs`.

Note that, `btrfs` has subvolumes, not sub-partitions. Think of them as directories, which you can create, delete, take snapshots of, assign quotas etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`Btrfs Assistant`](https://gitlab.com/btrfs-assistant/btrfs-assistant) is a GUI management tool to make managing a `Btrfs` filesystem more easily